# In a given field $F$, if $ab=0$, is it true that at least $a$ or $b$ has to be zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

The answer is true for integral domains, but I wonder if it is also true for any general field. Thanks.

Comment: Yes because a field is an integral  domain.

Comment: If suppose $a\neq 0$, multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$ to get $b=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume ${a\neq 0}$. Then ${a}$ has a multiplicative inverse. Multiply both left hand sides by this multiplicative inverse:

$${\Rightarrow a^{-1}\left(ab\right)=0}$$
$${\Rightarrow b=0}$$

So indeed, at least one of the elements must be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. **Every** field is an integral domain.